# Помогите разобраться с абстракцией php

Tags: php

Вообщем вот задание :

1. Реализовать абстрактный класс BaseMath содержащий 3 метода: `exp1($a, $b, $c)` и `exp2($a, $b, $c)`, `getValue()`.

- Метод exp1 реализует расчет по формуле a*(b^c).
- Метод exp2 реализует расчет по формуле (a/b)^c.
- Метод getValue() возвращает результат расчета класса наследника.

2. Реализовать класс F1 наследующий методы BaseMath, содержащий конструктор с параметрами ($a, $b, $c) и метод getValue().
   Класс реализует расчет по формуле `f=(a*(b^c)+(((a/c)^b)%3)^min(a,b,c))`.

что значит в первом задании 'Метод getValue() возвращает результат расчета класса наследника'?
вот мое решение, наверно оно не правильно. Хотелось бы узнать, что от меня требуется в задание и указать на ошибки в коде. Ну и если не сложно подсказать хороший ресурс для изучение ооп php.

```
   abstract class BaseMath {
        public function exp1($a, $b, $c) {
            return $a*($b**$c);
        }
        
        public function exp2($a, $b, $c) {
            return ($a/$b)**$c;
        }
        
        abstract function getValue(); 
    
    }
    class F1 extends BaseMath {
        
        function __construct($a,$b,$c) {
            $this->a = $a;
            $this->b = $b;
            $this->c = $c;

        }
        
        public function getValue() {
            return ($this->a*($this->b**$this->c)+((($this->a/$this->c)**$this->b)%3)**min($this->a,$this->b,$this->c));
        
          
        }
    }
    
    $text = new F1(1,1,1);
    var_dump ($text->getValue());
    var_dump($text->exp1(10,1,2));
```

Comment: А что конкретно в вашем решении вас смущает? Почему оно кажется неправильным? Задание настолько подробное, что что-либо сделать иначе довольно затруднительно))

Comment: Поля желательно объявить. И, скорее всего, предполагалось, что в getValue вы захотите использовать методы exp1 и exp2 =) А для того, чтобы это желание возникло, нужно было не знать про оператор `**`